# How to keep problematic pods while ensuring the number of healthy pods in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes, we can specify the replica of statefulset/deployment. Sometimes, one or more pods will be problematic. For example, the deployment have 3 replicas, and one pod not work well. How can we keep the problematic pod alive for troubleshooting, while creating a new one, to ensure there are 3 healthy pods ?

There are 4 pods in total

```
pod-healthy-0 Running
pod-healthy-1 Running
pod-healthy-2 Running
pod-problem-keep-for-debug Running
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `readinessProbe` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)

This will mark the pod(s) as "not ready" for traffic (they will show as `0/1 Ready`) if the check fails, and they will therefore not receive any requests. The pods will only be killed if the `livenessProbe` fails.